# What is the intuition behind transposed convolution?

Tags: transposed-convolution

I am confused with how I could use ConvTranspose2D function as I'm not familiar with how it is actually working.

What I understood is for a simple toy example of input size = (2x2), stride = 1, padding = 0, and kernel size = (4x4), and the output map size is 5x5, by multiplying each elements (scalars) to the kernel itself and add the overlapping convolution maps to create final output map of shape (5x5).

But with the options of different stride values and padding values, how is output map actually created? I have read https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-transposed-convolutional-layer-40e5e6e31c11 and have difficulty understanding the intuition behind how the output map is actually formed. The post says that stride and padding is not the same concept as the original convolution arithmetic, but I don't get why we have to compute new values such as s' and p' in the post to do transposed convolution.

So the main question is, how can I set up Conv2dTranspose function to upsample an image as the shape as what I want? (for example, upsample an image of 64x64 to 128x128, by setting appropriate stride and padding values with specific kernel size) What do I have to consider?